# Detecting change in a textbox without off-click with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js app that includes a form which can't be submitted until both of two input fields are filled in. The current code includes this as part of a mixin:

```
disableSubmit: (function() {
  return (this.get('field1.amout') == null) || (this.get('field2.amount') == null);
}).property('field1', 'field2'),
```

This *almost* behaves the way I want, except the submit button doesn't become enabled until the user clicks off the second input. How do I get the property to update without the user needing to click off?

**Edit:** Here's the hbs code:

```
<div class="l-notification-buttons-container">
  <div class="l-notification-button-container">
    {{input-value value=field1
      inputClassNames='l-input-textbox'
      isInvalid=inputInvalid
      invalidClass='input-is-invalid'
      disabled=isSaving}}
  </div>
  <div class="l-notification-button-container">
    {{input-value value=field2
      inputClassNames='l-input-textbox'
      isInvalid=inputInvalid
      invalidClass='input-is-invalid'
      disabled=isSaving}}
  </div>
  <div class="l-notification-button-container">
    {{button-loading isLoading=isSaving
      action="submitValues"
      disabled=disableSubmit
      labelTranslation="button.submit"
      class="button--blue l-submit-button"}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Chris. We'd need to please see a bit more code in order to figure out what is going on, including the hbs code. Have you tried to create a reproduction in Ember Twiddle?

Comment: Added hbs code. Anything else especially relevant?

Comment: Yes. Your {{input-value}} component.

Comment: Is that just a typo in the question or is that also in the code. The "this.get('field1.amout')"?